# sending already used variable via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I'm using jquery datepicker on a page. Next to datepicker i have a section which will show events on mouseenter of the datepicker. I have figured out a way to get the date into the header of this section. The problem i am having is getting that variable over to the php page that will be displayed on mousenter.

Below is the page that the datepicker and events will be shown:

```
<div id=events>
       <div id=eventcontent>
       </div>
           </div> 

           <div id=eventsheading>
           <div id=headingcontent>
           </div>
           </div>

      <div id = "datepicker">
      </div>
```

This is the Jquery i am using to fill in the header with the date (which works), send the same variable to events.php (which doesnt work), and show events.php in the content div (which does work as when i highlight a date, hello is shown):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-hover', function(e){

    var daynum1  =   $(this).text();
    var month1   =   $('.ui-datepicker-month').text();
    var year1    =   $('.ui-datepicker-year').text();

    var Date = daynum1 + " " + month1 + " " + year1;
    $('#headingcontent').html(Date);

    //ajax call with date information
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "events.php",
    type: "POST",
        data: {Date: Date},
        dataType: "html"
    });

   $.ajax({
  url: "events.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#eventcontent").append(html);
  }
});
});
```

Below is events.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['Date']))
{
    $date = $_POST['Date'];

echo <<<_END

<p>$date</p>

_END;
}
else
{
echo <<<_END


<p>hello!</p>

_END;

}
```

once i get this bit working, events PHP will be changed to select events from mysql.

To clarify, the problem i am having is getting variable date to send via ajax with this code:

```
//ajax call with date information
        var request = $.ajax({
        url: "events.php",
        type: "POST",
            data: {Date: Date},
            dataType: "html"
        });
```

i cant seem to find anywhere that explains how data: {...}, should be used and I'm guessing this is my problem.

Sorry if the code is just completely wrong i'm very new to learning it all and thanks for any help.

Comment: First of all: Don’t use variable names that collide with built-in objects - JS already has a `Date` object, so using that as a variable name is asking for trouble. (Yes, it is a local variable only in the code shown - but still, just don’t do it.)

Comment: And secondly - why are you making _two_ AJAX requests here? You are sending the data with the first one only - so in the second one, that value is of course not available. Just make that _one_ request, that send the data to the server, and then displays the response in the page.

Comment: @CBroe good point about the name, i'll change that. I'm quite new to all this, is it possible to explain further on how to make the second one a request?

Comment: You don’t need two requests. Make one POST request, that sends the data - and specify a success callback for that request.

Comment: first try to understand the scope of request and response, when you are making first request with post data using Date, it is available to your first request only so when you are trying to do second request it will go in else part as the Date was posted in first request, hope this make sense to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must not use variable names which collide with inbuilt objects as @CBroe said.
and rest like this

```
   var myDate = daynum1 + " " + month1 + " " + year1;
    $('#headingcontent').html(myDate);

   $.ajax({
    url: "events.php",
    type: "POST",
        data: {myDate: myDate},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
    $("#eventcontent").empty();  
    $("#eventcontent").append(html);
  }
    });
```

no need for second ajax call

Comment: thanks for this. My knowledge is very limited so far with this, but i was using the second ajax call to tell #eventcontent to use the new updated events.php within it. Is this is what is achieved by .append? I know this post the coorect information to event.php, but does it then load the new events.php into eventcontent?

Comment: @josh in that case you have to replace all the previous event data from that div for this use html(). See my updated post (if i clearly understand your requirement)